# Bootstrap Carousel is not visible when initialized inside another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular and bootstrap ui and attempting to get a bootstrap carousel working. For right now I am just using the demo code provided in the documentation. If I initialize the function as soon as the page loads it works fine.

However my end goal is pass a variable that won't be defined until after the user inputs some information so I need to initialize the carousel later.  When I try to do this I don't get any errors in the console and when I check the html it shows that the carousel has been inserted into the DOM. However no part of it is showing up. I just get a blank page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<div style="height: 305px">
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

**JS (working) :**

```
$scope.carousel = function(totalMatches){ 


    console.log("called");
    console.log(totalMatches);

    $scope.myInterval = -1;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
        $scope.addSlide = function() {
            var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
            slides.push({
            image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
            text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
            ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
            });
         };
            for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
              $scope.addSlide();
             }

};


    $scope.carousel(totalMatches);
```

**JS (not working):**

```
$scope.findSomething = function(){

    do some stuff in here to define totalMatches

    $scope.carousel(totalMatches);
};

$scope.carousel = function(totalMatches){ 


    console.log("called");
    console.log(totalMatches);

    $scope.myInterval = -1;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
        $scope.addSlide = function() {
            var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
            slides.push({
            image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
            text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
            ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
            });
         };
            for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
              $scope.addSlide();
             }

};
```

Comment: The JS code is close to unreadable without proper intendation... Does your  async version print  "called" to the console?

Comment: yes the called prints to the console and there are no errors. I will fix the indentation. Thanks